# How can I obtain up-to-date packages?

Tags: apt, updates

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 which I've downloaded and installed recently. How can I get packages for up-to-date versions of software? For example I can only find g++ up to 4.9, or Boost up to 1.55. g++5.1 was released more than a month ago. I have some packages like `git` which is just 2.1.4 compared to the latest release of 2.4.2.

I found a few sources discussing "Software and Updates" settings. I've enabled updates from all four sources (`vivid-security`, `vivid-proposed`, `vivid-updates`, `vivid-backports`) but this has not made any difference. I also found some sources about manually editing your sources file in /etc, but I also found this to be ineffective.

How can I find some reasonably up-to-date packages for Ubuntu? Or does Ubuntu simply not ship any updated packages from any source and I'll have to manually track down new sources for every individual piece of software that I want to keep updated?

Comment: If you aim to have the latest version of all your programs, maybe Ubuntu is not the Linux distro for you.

Comment: you can simply search for corresponding PPAs on Launchpad like [this one](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging) but remember the latest doesn't mean the most stable.

Comment: Having the two questions be duplicates implies that I care why, which I don't. I simply care about fixing it.

Comment: for example git https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa simply add the PPA and you'll have the latest stable.

Answer (score 1):

As xangua said:

> If you aim to have the latest version of all your programs, maybe Ubuntu > is not the Linux distro for you.

Compile the latest versions themselves or search for a matching [PPA](https://launchpad.net/).

I think , adding a PPA is an efficient way. In any case, this is a good compromise.

Eg: `GCC 5.x`:

- [ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  ```
- [ppa:nicola-onorata/toolchain](https://launchpad.net/~nicola-onorata/+archive/ubuntu/toolchain)

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nicola-onorata/toolchain
  ```

Or `Git 2.4.x`

- [ppa:git-core/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
  ```

After adding a PPA, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

And finally a word:

You should add *(vivid)-proposed* only if you know what you're doing. More infos [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).